# In SemVer what should the assembly+file versions be when release a beta to the public?

Tags: .net, nuget, versioning, semantic-versioning

Lets say we are Releasing a .net library for first time. We want to go through a Beta + Release Candidate phase to get feedback from early adopters.

So in the context of [SemVer](http://semver.org/) we would initially be releasing Version `1.0.0-Beta1`. With increasing betas and release candidates after that.

For the sake of argument let say our  current version number is `0.3.0`

So from the SemVer we need to derive what to place in the various .net version placeholders. Those being:

#### 1. Nuget Version

Used to name the nuget package and also used by nuget to sort the package and derive if it is a pre-release

#### 2. Assembly Version

Remember assemblies may be strong named and binding redirects may complicate moving between betas when assembly version changes

#### 3. Assembly File Version

Which maps to "File version" in the file properties dialog

#### 4. Assembly Informational Version

Which maps to "Product version" in the file properties dialog

Comment: I'm not sure this is just opinion-based because there are [rules around using the assembly & file version](http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/556041) that have specific consequences, which are [hard to follow](http://techblog.ranjanbanerji.com/post/2008/06/26/Net-Assembly-Vs-File-Versions.aspx) and would benefit from a definitive answer here.

Comment: Here's what I think fwiw: Keep the file version numbers the same as the nuget version, following semver. Assembly Version changes indicates breaking changes and incompatibility so only change that when you bump the major version.  Refs http://techblog.ranjanbanerji.com/post/2008/06/26/Net-Assembly-Vs-File-Versions.aspx & http://semver.org/

Answer (score 1):

I don't think SemVer aims to resolve all 4 items you listed, but the very first one. It gives end users a way to understand whether they are using the latest, and on which build type (stable, beta, alpha, and so on). It cannot apply to most version number scenarios, as those scenarios require 4 segments with pure numbers.

Thus, for my own NuGet packages, I follow SemVer to set NuGet package version, but stick to [AssemblyInfo Task](https://web.archive.org/web/20130509173926/http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/AssemblyInfoTaskvers) when I compile the binaries.

Well, that's just how I handle the version numbers and others might have their styles.

Comment: OK but if the SemVer is 1.0.0-Beta1 what what do you use for the others?

Comment: Just updated my answer. I used AssemblyInfo Task to modify AssemblyInfo.cs (or .vb or any other) so as to set Assembly Version, Assembly File Version, and so on during compilation.